# how to use java api to monitor master, regionserver and zookeeper working

Tags: java, hbase

I know I can use log in $HBASE_HOME/log to know how they work and what they have done. For example, master controll regionserver transit data to another one, then I can find the information in logs.

Now I suppose to build java interface to monitor what master,regionserver and zookeeper have done.
However, I don't find a proper way to get information of what they have done.

Is there any good method help me do that?
I don't want to use log in $HBASE_HOME/log manually.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at HBase UI at http://host:60010? It shows performance information at the region server and table level. Also, take a look at tcollector which is able to collect and store hbase metrics. Last but not least, you can monitor HBase metrics with JMX.

Comment: jmx can provide instant report of what they have done?
I thought it can provide only information of system details.

Comment: I know that hbase ui shows performance information, but I want to use java to develop something, so I want to use java to get performance information, is that possible?